# Http404 django python

Tags: python-3.x, http-status-code-404

Help to implement this code

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    '''Данная функция отображает полное страницу поста в блоге'''
    context = {'post': post_id_detail[pk]}
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

If the user enters in the address bar with his hands http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/6 /, then there is no such object in our mini-database. We will get an error.
We need to control this. If the requested object is missing, raise an exception with the message.

```
if there is a problem:
raise <Exception>('<problem description>')
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is closed implemented in this way

```
try:
        pk = post_id_detail[pk]
    except IndexError:
        raise Http404("Статья не найдена")
```